# Android Studio 3.1.2 fails with StackOverFlowError when I have the proguard on

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I can no longer compile my project with proguard after I upgrade to the latest gradle 3.1.2 on Android.

I can compile the project fine without the proguard enabled. But when I turn it on like the following

```
debug {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debugConfig
        }
```

the project fails to compile and I see this error message

```
Cause: java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at proguard.classfile.instruction.InstructionFactory.create(InstructionFactory.java:296)
    at proguard.classfile.attribute.visitor.StackSizeComputer.evaluateInstructionBlock(StackSizeComputer.java:325)
    at proguard.classfile.attribute.visitor.StackSizeComputer.visitBranchInstruction(StackSizeComputer.java:207)
    at proguard.classfile.instruction.BranchInstruction.accept(BranchInstruction.java:141)
    at proguard.classfile.attribute.visitor.StackSizeComputer.evaluateInstructionBlock(StackSizeComputer.java:366)
    at proguard.classfile.attribute.visitor.StackSizeComputer.visitBranchInstruction(StackSizeComputer.java:207)
    at proguard.classfile.instruction.BranchInstruction.accept(BranchInstruction.java:141)
    at proguard.classfile.attribute.visitor.StackSizeComputer.evaluateInstructionBlock(StackSizeComputer.java:366)
    at proguard.classfile.attribute.visitor.StackSizeComputer.visitBranchInstruction(StackSizeComputer.java:207)
```

What would cause this error?

Comment: You should not minify and shrink your resources in the debug build. Move the 2 lines (`minifyEnabled true` and `shrinkResources true`) in the release `buildType`

Comment: @MatPag It doesn't work on release as well. I only turned it on debug to eliminate other possible problems.

Comment: Tried to invalidate the cache and restart AS?

Comment: @MatPag thanks I did that too. It didn't work. I cleaned it multiple times and also tried to run it on the terminal to see if I can get more verbose message but I don't see any other useful message.

Comment: Have you tried adding some flags to the terminal build? like this: `./gradlew assembleRelease --stacktrace` or `./gradlew assembleRelease --debug` trying to get more useful outputs?

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: @SiPe I wasnt able to find a solution but I found out which was causing this. It was a library that was obfuscated and even the package name was obfuscated. So my assumption is that the proguard was trying to obfuscate the obfuscated library and then obfuscated again which was causing this.